# Where to find old Fortran library libF77.so.3

Tags: solaris, fortran

We have some old binaries which ran on Sun SPARC systems from around 2000, and we'd like to run them again (we do not have the source code.) I tried running the binaries on a Sun Blade 1500 with a SPARC processor and Solaris 10, but I get errors like

> ld.so.1: plot: fatal: libF77.so.3: open failed: No such file or directory

I added a new drive with more space, installed Solaris 10, Java 8 JRE, and Oracle Developer Studio 12.6 with the hope of getting the libraries needed. Alas, I get the same result. It looks like libF77.so.3 used to be part of [Sun Studio 12](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-4155/runtime.libraries.html). Any idea where to find it now?

Comment: let me know if the solution below works for you if not we can find alternative

Comment: Try https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/sdlc-decommission-333274.html . I can't verify the links work; they require a support contract, which I don't have.

Comment: Thanks Mark-- alas, I was unable to find an older version which contained this library.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `libF77.so.3`, you should find it under this path `/opt/SUNWspro/lib/`. Also, check if you have it and if the directory is in your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. 
`libF77.so` is only distributed with the `Sun F77` compiler, so binaries should be linked mit static Fortran libraries.

Basically, you need Fortran 77 legacy libraries, which comprised of:

```
libF77.so.2
libF77.so.3
libF77.so.4
libF77_mt.so.2
libF77_mt.so.3
libF77_mt.so.4
libFposix.so.1
libFposix_c.so.1
libM77.so.2
libV77.so.2
libV77.so.3
```

You can download [here](ftp://ftp.openwatcom.org/install/open-watcom-f77-linux-1.9)

Comment: Thanks Goro-- how would you recommend installing this file? I tried creating a symbolic link at /lib/libF77so.3 to it but got "ld.so.1: plot: fatal: /lib/libF77.so.3: wrong ELF data format: ELFDATA2LSB".

Comment: Dear @lava37 this file is executable, it should work once you click on it and it will install C++ compiler Fortran 77 compiler and the library `libF77.so.3`, did you install it? the message you got means either libF77.so.3 is corrupted or not exist?

Comment: Attempting to execute open-watcom-f77-linux-1.9 results in "bash: /Desktop/open-watcom-f77-linux-1.9: Invalid argument".  I redownloaded the file and made it excutable both times, and tried adding --help or -help but got the same results.

Comment: Linux/x86 binaries won't run on Solaris/SPARC